# what is the preffered configuration of NIC for Kafka - team or bond configuration?

Tags: linux, networking, redhat, bonding, network-teaming

We have 22 Kafka brokers physical machines (DELL HW) that should be finally installed as production Kafka cluster. when OS should be RHEL 7.9 version

we are not sure about - TEAM vs BOND for Kafka cluster.

from my understanding team network configuration is maybe the preferred configuration?

but I am not sure about this.

Bonding:- Bonding refers to create a bond or aggregation of two or more links into one in order to provide failover and redundancy to the network.

Teaming:- Is a new way implementation of bonding and provides a separate driver. We have both drivers available as of now, and can implement either of them as per requirement.

Advantages of Teaming

1. Support for IPv6 (NA/NS) link monitoring
2. Teaming has a small kernel module which provides the same implementation with more features.
3. Less performance overhead
4. By default, Teamed interface is capable of working with D-Bus and Unix Domain Sockets.
5. Full userspace runtime control
6. Modular design allows function extensible option in future
7. Load balancing feature added for LACP support
8. Use of NetworkManager(nmcli) to manage our network connections

Teaming provides more features and a way towards automation as network manager can handle the interfaces with modular design and hence considered a modern way of handing the interfaces.

hopefully to get yours ideas and if its team, then on which team configuration is better to use ?